# How and where can I sort an array of Django <django.utils.functional.lazy> objects?

Tags: python, django, sorting, internationalization, lazy-evaluation

I have a list of tuples with countries/cities combinations from which I populate a select field in django.

I'm loading placeholders for the select options using a configparser in my `settings.py`:

```
scope_value_list = dict(raw_parser.items('scope_value_list'))
CATEGORIES = SimpleNamespace(**{
  "SCOPE_CHOICES": [(code_tuple[1], _(scope_value_list[code_tuple[0]].partition('{% trans "')[2].partition('" %}')[0])) for code_tuple in raw_parser.items('scope_list')],
  ...
})
```

A bit cumbersome but I cannot provide hardcoded translations outside of the django.po/mo files and haven't found a better solution than to include my .ini file in my `makemessages` calls and then strip the translation flags as shown above to build my list of choices.

However this means my SCOPE_CHOICES contains lazy-translated-objects and not actual translations, so I have:

```
[('eu', <django.utils.functional.lazy.<locals>.__proxy__ object at 0x7ff11f7ad470>), ('eu-at', <django.utils.functional.lazy.<locals>.__proxy__ object at 0x7ff11f7adba8>), ('eu-be', <django.utils.functional.lazy.<locals>.__proxy__ object at 0x7ff11f7adc50>), ('eu-bg', <django.utils.functional.lazy.<locals>.__proxy__ object at 0x7ff11f7adcc0>), ('eu-hr', <django.utils.functional.lazy.<locals>.__proxy__ object at 0x7ff11f7b6278>),...]
```

This all works (yay), but when I display the select field in any template it will go by the order in the tuple (array would be the same), so countries are not sorted A-Z by their actual name and I can't figure out how to do it in a language-agnostic way. I understand that lazy-translation will be run when "when it is needed" so the only place, I could come up with and can actually access the choices is in `forms.py` where I tried like so:

```
  scope = forms.ChoiceField(
    required=True,
    label=_("Scope"),
    choices=sorted(settings.CATEGORIES.SCOPE_CHOICES, key=lambda x: x[1]),
    help_text=_("User participation scope.")
  )
```

because from there on it's displayed in the template:

```
<div class="form-group">
  {{ form.scope.label_tag }}
  <div class="">
    {{ form.scope.errors }}
    {{ form.scope }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Sadly it doesn't work and the items are still in the original order meaning not sorted alphabetically in any language I'm displaying them.

**Question therefore**:
How and where can I sort an array of Django lazy-translation-objects?